# Google Earth Extension to export georeferenced image?

Tags: georeferencing, google-earth, imagery, extensions

Has somebody coded an extension to Google Earth that will export a georeferenced image from google earth? Google Earth and Google Earth Pro only export the image *.jpg *.png etc and don't export the jgw or pgw file that contains the georeferencing information. This would be a very handy extension to have since google earth pro usually has the most up to date, freely available Imagery for the regions that I work in.

Comment: Be careful with what you want, there is a lot of copyright things around, which makes aerial photograph not exactly free

Comment: I don't think anyone can do that because of copyright issues. If your organization has the funding, there are services that can do that. I did a trial of NearMap and they use similar photography to Google (and in very high resolution). You can export georeferenced TIFs or JPEGs. The service is expensive though, hence why I only did the trial.

Comment: What copyright issues? Google Earth Pro is now freely available so the images they provide are public domain as far as I can tell. Thanks for the tip about NearMap it looks better than most services I have seen.

Comment: Public Domain ?

Comment: @PROBERT Ok Public Domain is incorrect however reading Google's own guidelines it seems like one time uses or for small distribution is ok as long as the copyright is visible or correct attribution is given. I still don't see how adding georeferencing information changes the situation because your resolution vs area limited in terms of what you can export. Aerial survey companies want to sell you a product that is both detailed and covers a lot of area.